# I am trying to read content from input.txt file, store them in a 2D array, print array content

Tags: java

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab8 {    
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String line, filename = "input.txt";
    FileReader fp = new FileReader("input.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(fp);
    while(scan.hasNextLine())
    {
        line=scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);

    }
    int [][] matrix = new int [3][5];

    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            matrix[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        //declare a sum variable and initialize to zero
        int sum = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            sum +=scan.nextInt(sum);
        }
        //Compute the average of j-th quiz for all students
        //Print the sum of all quizzes for the i-th student 
        System.out.println("Total Quiz result for student 1 is ");
        System.out.println("Total Quiz result for student 2 is ");
        System.out.println("Total Quiz result for student 3 is ");
        System.out.println("Total Quiz result for student 4 is ");
    } 


    for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
    {

        int sum=0;

        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            //update sum of j-th quiz
            //by adding the score of i-th student

        }
        //Compute the average of j-th quiz for all students
        //print the average corrected to two decimal places
        System.out.println("Average of Quiz 1 is ");
        System.out.println("Average of Quiz 2 is ");
        System.out.println("Average of Quiz 3 is ");
        System.out.println("Average of Quiz 4 is ");
        System.out.println("Average of Quiz 5 is ");

    } scan.close();
 }

}
```

Before I start, just want point out I am new to java coding.     The only output I am getting from this is the content from the input.txt file :10
9
10
8
7
7
8
9
8
10
6
7
8
9
10
and then the error prompts :Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found. Any help is greatly appreciated.   The output of the following code should look like this:

User Input is read from text file
Total Quiz result for student 1 is 44 Total Quiz result for student 2 is 42 Total Quiz result for student 3 is 40 Average of Quiz 1 is 7.67
Average of Quiz 2 is 8.00 Average of Quiz 3 is 9.00 Average of Quiz 4 is 8.33 Average of Quiz 5 is 9.00

Comment: How are contents stored? Number per line or all the numbers in one line? I think it is all the numbers are in one line. Am I right? Or can you post the contents of the file as it is?

Comment: the content is stored 1 number per line.

Comment: Could you post the content of the file?

Comment: You read each number, and print it, without storing it anywhere, and you reach the end of the file.  Then you try to read 15 more lines, but you're at the end of the file.

Comment: Didn't know it was that bad, sorry!  like I said, I am quite new to this. The job was to store each number(from the input.txt file) in a 2D array.

Comment: You probably need to reset the scanner to start at the beginning after you've  printed each line.  Or you can store the number from each line in the array right after printing it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using `Scanner` object multiple times to read the input from the file. The thing when you use `nextInt()` or `nextLine()`, the pointer moves forward and reaches EOF. So, to reset the pointer just close the file resources and reopen to read it again.

I edited your code:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab8 {    
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String line, filename = "input.txt";
    FileReader fp = new FileReader("input.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(fp);
    /*while(scan.hasNextLine()) // -> Instead of printing here, print in the for loop below
    {
        line=scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);

    }*/
    int [][] matrix = new int [3][5];

    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            line=scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);  // print here.
            matrix[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(line);
        }
    }
    scan.close();                      // close the scanner
    fp.close();                        // close the file reader
    fp = new FileReader("input.txt");  // reopen file reader
    scan = new Scanner(fp);            // reopen scanner

    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        //declare a sum variable and initialize to zero
        int sum = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {
            sum +=scan.nextInt();
        }
        //Compute the average of j-th quiz for all students
        //Print the sum of all quizzes for the i-th student 
        System.out.println("Total Quiz result for student 1 is ");
        System.out.println("Total Quiz result for student 2 is ");
        System.out.println("Total Quiz result for student 3 is ");
        System.out.println("Total Quiz result for student 4 is ");
    } 


    for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
    {

        int sum=0;

        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            //update sum of j-th quiz
            //by adding the score of i-th student

        }
        //Compute the average of j-th quiz for all students
        //print the average corrected to two decimal places
        System.out.println("Average of Quiz 1 is ");
        System.out.println("Average of Quiz 2 is ");
        System.out.println("Average of Quiz 3 is ");
        System.out.println("Average of Quiz 4 is ");
        System.out.println("Average of Quiz 5 is ");

    } scan.close();
 }

}
```

Closing `Scanner` object is not enough. You have to close the `FileReader` object to reset the pointer in the file.

I hope it helped you.